# Extract data from ASCII file with grep/AWK

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a long ASCII log-file from a simulation and need to extract some data from it.

The lines I want have the structure:

```
 Main step=     1 a= 0.00E+00 b=-6.85E-08 c= 4.58E-08
```

The phrase "Main step" is only used in the lines I want. This is easy to grep for, but I also want to include the next line following the line above, which has the structure:

```
 Fine step=     1 t=-1.31854E+01
```

Note that "Fine step" is used other places in the log-file.

My question boils down to this: How can I extract the lines containing a keyword/phrase (here "Main step") and also make sure that I get the next following line using grep or AWK or some other standard Linux program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)

```
sed -n '/Main step/,/./p' inputFile
```

This prints only the lines in a range starting from `Main step` and ending with `.` (the wildcard). Effectively, every line which reads `Main step` and the following are printed.

Answer (score 1):

Posted according to the tag [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). And the one through awk's getline function,

```
awk '/Main step/{print; getline; print}' file
```

It would print the Main step line and also the next line.

Answer (score 1):

Because you tagged "grep", and since this is the most obvious solution to me:

```
grep -A1 'Main step' file
```

...although this will add "--" between matches. So to get the same output as the awk and sed answer:

```
grep -A1 'Main step' file | grep -v '^--$'
```